# Get value of hidden field appended to table by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a new row appended to a table by AJAX in a function. I would like to search for a hidden field's value appended by the AJAX call. The function will append a new row every time the ajax call is successful.Every time before it appends, I would like to check the table if the hidden value exists. Please help?

```
var newRow = '<tr class="products_rows"><td><img src="'+siteurl+'assets/img/p/'+parsedDetails['image_name']+'" height="34px"></td><td class="product_name">'
+parsedDetails['name']+'<input type="hidden" class="product_id" val="'+parsedDetails['id']+'"></td><td class="product-quantity"><div class="q_input">'
+'<input type="text" value="1" style="float:left; width:40px;" class="reload_class" readonly="readonly">'
+'</div><div class="arrow_img"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/arrow_top.png" id="increase_quantity_01" class="increase_quantity" /><br/>'
+'<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/arrow_bottom.png" class="decrease_quantity" /></div></td>'
+'<td id="product_price_'+product_id+'" class="product_price">'+parsedDetails['price']+'</td><td>Delete</td></tr>';                                
$('#products_table').append(newRow);
```

Comment: how are you calling the AJAX? with a click?

Comment: you can give id to the hidden field and access the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad. I cannot get the value is because I used "val" instead of "value" in html... Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique `id` or `data-` attribute to your new row, like this:

```
var newRow = "<tr class='products_rows' data-value='" + hiddenValue + "> ......
```

Then use jQuery's selectors to check for this value.

```
if $('tr.products_rows[data-value="' + hiddenValue '"]').length > 0 {
    $('#productsTable').appendRow(newRow);
}
```

Comment: the newRow is in the AJAX call. The checking of the value is in another function

Comment: Then why not do it server side and have the ajax call return nothing if the hidden value has already been taken?

Comment: Do you mean that there are no ways to get an appended field's value, @CamelBlues?

Comment: Where is the hidden field's value coming from? If it's coming from the server, you can always return the value of the field with the ajax call. Either way you can always give the hidden field an id and check the value with jQuery.

Comment: The hidden field value is auto generated with an ajax call. after a successful ajax call, it appends a row to the table. I tried to search the table with the class of the appended rows but it cannot find the value